# Setting OS environmental variables in Angular-CLI

Tags: angular, angular-cli, jestjs, angular7, nrwl

#### Context:

(For the case that I'm running into an XY-Problem)

For various reasons we recently decided to modularise our Angular application. To achieve this we moved to `angular-cli` with a `Nrwl/Nx workspace` from an age-old manual webpack build. We are using Jest for our unit tests and our build server is Bamboo. To supply Bamboo with understandable test results we use `jest-bamboo-reporter`. Our test builders are `@nrwl/builders:jest`.

#### Problem:

To test our whole application we naturally need to test all of the libs as well as the apps. This all works fine, with the following setup:

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "npm-run-all test:app:* test:lib:*",
    "test:app:first": "set JEST_REPORT_FILE=report/test-report-first.json&& ng test first",
    "test:app:second": "set JEST_REPORT_FILE=report/test-report-second.json&& ng test second",
    "test:lib:lib1": "set JEST_REPORT_FILE=report/test-report-lib1.json&& ng test lib1",
    "test:lib:lib2": "set JEST_REPORT_FILE=report/test-report-lib2.json&& ng test lib2",
    ...
    "test:lib:xy": "set JEST_REPORT_FILE=report/test-report-xy.json&& ng test xy"
}
```

The only thing keeping us from having this nice and tidy are the constant `JEST_REPORT_FILE` environmental variable definitions that tell the reporter where the output should land. Is there a nicer way to do this? I would love to specify the environmental variable in the `ng test` description of each lib.